# Auto suggest with 20,000 entries

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am building a form that uses autosuggest.  The way it works is I load about 20,000+ customers into my angularjs app.  Then when the user types into the input field the name of the customer they want to lookup, I only show the customers that match that the user typed in.  Everytime the user types in a character the function to lookup   $scope.search1_autosuggest() runs again.

I was wondering if the way I'm doing it is efficient or not? Since it is a large set of data I want to make sure the speed is fast enough for the autosuggestion.

controller.js

```
 $scope.search1_autosuggest=function(type){
      var results=$scope.original_data;
      var new_results=[];
   if(type=="phone"){

     var typed_result=$scope.search1.phone;

      for (var key in results) {
          var phone_result = results[key].home_phone;

          if(phone_result.match(typed_result)){
              new_results.push(results[key]);
          }
      }
      $scope.info=new_results;


   }

};
```

partial.html

```
 <form>
    Phone: <input type="text" data-ng-model="search1.phone" data-ng-
 change="search1_autosuggest('phone')"/><br/>
    Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="search1.name" data-ng-    
 change="search1_autosuggest('name')"/><br/>
    Address: <input type="text" data-ng-model="search1.address" data-ng-  
 change="search1_autosuggest('address')"/><br/>
</form>
<h3>Customers</h3>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="field in info">
            <a href="" data-ng-click="retrieve_single(field.id)"> name:{{field.name}}.     
  address:{{field.address}}.    Phone:{{field.home_phone}}.</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: how come database engines efficiently query huge amount of data (much more than 20,000 items)? they use *indexes*. When you fetch the data you should create an index . I think there are also some good client side databases for this purpose. Also you should limit your results to reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: If you're ok sorting your data then a binary search will move you from O(n) to O(log n).  If you go this route you may want to split phone, name and address into individual tables so they can each be sorted (possibly linking the table entries with indexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for a small timed delay between the entry of characters (somewhere between 0.4 - 0.6 seconds works well). When the timer expires then do the lookup. This seems responsive to user without hammering lookup.

Use a timer that is reset on the keyup event.

Comment: FWIW this is often called "debouncing".

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this recently is to wait until the user has typed at least a couple of chars, then I do a async call to retrieve the matching records. This way it reduces the amount of wait time while the page loads

I've also put a timer in the keyup event so that it doesn't try to resolve on every keypress

Answer (score 1):

That's a big dataset. Any pre-filtering of the dataset that you can perform, based on other information (geographical, timeframe, etc.) will greatly help. We did an address entry system at one point which leveraged the postal database (available free) to use zip codes to restrict which cities were selectable, city and zipcode to restrict which streets were selectable, city and zipcode and street to restrict which addresses were selectable (eg, knowing that only 2070 to 3400 Main Street are possible matches).

Any pre-indexing of the data which you can perform will also help. Avoid linear search during interaction time as much as possible. You may want to break your name list up into smaller chunks -- divide into buckets by those first few characters, as Jasonscript suggested -- to reduce the problem to a more manageable one.

Remember too that you don't have to yield all the matches at  once. You can fetch the ones that fit on screen, display, them, continue fetching the rest as a background task which is interrupted if new search conditions become available. As others have noted, this hides some of the delay from the user. (Many websites do something like this; BoingBoing, for example, fetches only a limited number of entries initially and then grabs more when you scroll down far enough that it thinks you'll need them.)

Make sure your data's current and clean, if this will be visible to customers rather than to your own staff.  The last thing you want is for them to be scrolling through and run across the test entry for "Farley, Charles Hugh" or something like that.

Have fun. When you get this right, it *really* impresses users.